# Elementor custom icons not displayed

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[image]

As you can see, the only thing displayed is the title. I tried to use a simple set of black icons from fontello or icomoon and same thing happens. What could be the issue?

Comment: Hi Cristian. Have you check the browser console to see if there is some javascript error causing the problem?

Comment: Hello! Yes, I checked everything. But I found out what was the cause of my problem. Whenever you create a new set of icons with fontello you need to set an unique name, which I didn't. It worked after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are using fontello to create icon sets you need to set a unique name set for it, or it will cause a display error on your website.